# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: []("name")

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a single document from firestore in flutter, when document is present it should return the data when document is not present it should return null data, What i tried so far:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Profile').document(user.uid).snapshots(),
 
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return new showProfile(
            name: "null",
            email: "null",
            pin: "null",
            state: "null",
          );
        }else {
          var userDocument = snapshot.data;
          return new showProfile(
            name: userDocument["name"],
            email: userDocument["email"],
            pin: userDocument["pin"],
            state: userDocument["state"],
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

but i am getting this error

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't be `Firestore.collection` instead `Firestore.instance.collection`?

Comment: @Captivity No it should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`snapshot.data` is null thus you get that error, most probably the `user.uid` is null that's why you are not getting any data, you have to do the following:

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async*{
var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
yield* Firestore.instance.collection('Profile').document(user.uid).snapshots()
}
```

And then inside the `StreamBuilder` use the method `getData()`:

```
   return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getData(),
```